# Multiplying two logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I've searched for some answer already, but couldn't find any solution to this problem. Apparently, there's no rule for the product of two logarithms. How would I then find the exact solution of this problem?
$$
\log(x) = \log(100x) \, \log(2)
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How would I then find the exact solution of this problem?

Manipulate the equation to isolate $x$.
\begin{align*}
\log(x) &= (\log(100)+\log(x))\log(2)  \\
\log(x) &=\log(100)\log(2)+\log(x)\log(2)\\
\log(x)-\log(x)\log(2)&=\log(100)\log(2)\\
\log(x)(1-\log(2))&=\log(100)\log(2)  \\
\log(x)&=\log(100)\log(2)/(1-\log(2))\\
\end{align*}
Then resolve $x$ with whatever base your logarithm is using. E.g. with base 10, 
$$x\approx7.267$$

Comment: This should be it if I look at how it's worked out.

Answer (score 19):

$\log(x) = (\log(100) + \log(x))\cdot\log2$

$\log(x) = \log(100)\cdot\log(2) + \log(x)\cdot\log(2)$

This is a linear equation in $\log(x)$!

Comment: One variable does not a line make, but a point.

Comment: @Ax. That's linear as in "polynomial equation of degree 1", not as in "defining a line".

Comment: Oh right, the other variable is the base of the logarithm.

Comment: @Ax. Set the $x$ axis to be $\log(x)$ and the $y$ axis to be regular $y$.  Then it becomes a line.

Comment: @SimpleArt, where is $y$?

Comment: @Ax. this may help clarify things https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation

Answer (score 6):

The question does not specify the base $B$ of the logarithm, but it will affect the solution, so we make it explicit:
\begin{align}
\log_B(x) 
&= \log_B(100\, x) \, \log_B(2) \\
&= (\log_B(100) + \log_B(x)) \, \log_B(2) \iff \\
(1 - \log_B(2)) \log_B(x)  
&= \log_B(2) \log_B(100) \\
\end{align}
For $B = 2$ the LHS vanishes and we have no solution, as the logarithms on the RHS do not vanish.

For $B \ne 2$ we can continue:
\begin{align}
\log_B(x) = \frac{\log_B(2) \, \log_B(100)}{1 - \log_B(2)} = f(B) \iff \\
x = B^{f(B)} =  B^{(\log_B(2) \, \log_B(100))/(1 - \log_B(2))} 
\end{align}

For $B=e$ one gets
$$
x = e^{f(e)} = e^{10.4025\dotsb} = 32944.48\dotsb
$$

Here are graphs of $f(B)$:

[image: close view]
[image: farer view]

(Links to larger versions: [left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJYBW.png), [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea0vp.png))

Comment: I believe that is the incorrect approximate value of the solution.

Comment: I see now that you used value e as your base. The solution, however, is still wrong.

Comment: Ah yes. I separated it now.

Comment: If B is not specified, it automatically means that it is 10.

Comment: While true, people do use e to denote log. Personally, I find the log notation of base 10 to be silly. But hey, base 10 is "silent" wherever you go.

Answer (score 2):

Fill in details *after* you check the basic properties of logarithms, and assuming $\;\log=\log_{10}\;$:

$$\log x=\log 100x\cdot\log2=\left(\log100+\log x\right)\log2\implies$$

$$(1-\log2)\log x=2\log2\implies\ldots$$

Comment: A term has disappeared

Comment: @egreg I don't think so....which one?

Comment: Oh, assuming $\log=\log_{10}$. Why?

Comment: @egreg My logic was that such an elementary question surely is of high school level, and there they usually use $\;\log=\log_{10}\;$, as shown in calculators. That's the only reason.

Comment: Yeah,  whatever happened to the "standard" notation of  `ln` for natural logs and `lc` for "common," or log-base 10 ?   :-(

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My "standard" notation in high school was `ln` for natural logs, and `log` for base 10 logs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have never, ever heard of that "standard notation", by which I mean some widely used and more or less international notation. In my case, and my children's, the notation was as Brian says.

Comment: @DonAntonio It may be a low-level question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere online. Therefor I think it was reasonable to post it here.

Comment: @P.Yntema Please do note that elementary $\;\neq\;$ low-level. The problem is that in this site we cannot know what lever the asker has, so by "elementary" in this case I mean that this seems like a high school level question.